# Why arent packages being recognised in this function?

Tags: python, yfinance

I am running the following script:

```
# STEP 1: import packages, declare tindexes
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt

bnpl_tindex = ["APT.AX","Z1P.AX","LFS.AX","SZL.AX","HUM.AX","SPT.AX","OPY.AX","IOU.AX","LBY.AX","DOU.AX"]
target_dates = pd.date_range(start=dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=365), end=dt.date.today(), freq="M").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
target_dates = target_dates.append(pd.Index([dt.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]))
target_dates.sort_values()

#STEP 2:  source functions
from collect_index_data import collect_index_data


#DELETE LATER... TESTING!
collect_index_data(bnpl_tindex, target_dates)
#
```

collect_index_data is as follows:

```
def  collect_index_data(ticker_list,date_list):
    if (bool(ticker_list) and all(isinstance(elem, str) for elem in ticker_list) )==False:
        sys.exit('Input should be a list or a single string.')
    else:
        print("Components of Index: ")

        #initialise dictionary
        d = {}

        #loop through ticker list
        for x in ticker_list:
            d["DF.{0}".format(x)] = yf.Ticker(x)
            #testing
            print(x)
        #testing
        print(d)
```

and I get the following error message

```
Components of Index: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\Files\Programming\Python\run_tindex_data.py", line 27, in <module>
    collect_index_data(bnpl_tindex, target_dates)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\Files\Programming\Python\collect_index_data.py", line 12, in collect_index_data
    d["DF.{0}".format(x)] = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
NameError: name 'yf' is not defined
```

My question is why is yfinance package not being recognised in my function?
I could import it inside the function, but I plan to run the function multiple times in a script - so this would be computationally wasteful.

thanks!

Comment: "collect_index_data" is also a module. Import it into that. Each function has a reference to the module in which it was defined and uses the namespace of that module, not of the module in which it was called or imported into.

Comment: You need to import it in the module that your function is in. It will only be imported once then, when that module is imported. And yfinance is imported already so it shouldn't slow down anything at all.